# how to get data from dynamodb using rest api

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How do I fetch Amazon DynamoDB data using a RESTful API?

Is there a way to get Amazon DynamoDB data using a REST url, and if so what are the required parameters to pass in the url?

We have considered the DynamoDB endpoint as the url and append it with the `accesskey` and the `secretaccesskey`, is anything more required to append to the url?

If any one has tried this with DynamoDB RESTful API, can you give me an example of how to get table data?

A sample url would also be good, something showing how to connect to DynamoDB through a RESTful API.

Ideally, a sample url with all the parameters required.

Answer (score 12):

There is an AWS documentation including an example:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/MakingHTTPRequests.html

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like this isn't as easy as creating a curl or postman request. Generating the `Authorization`  header isn't as easy as putting your AWS keys in the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use API gateway which points to a Lambda function to fetch the data from DynamoDB. End point of your API gateway URL will be your rest end point.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how Dynamo works, you will have to build your own RESTful API (i.e. use the AWS SDK for PHP) that hits Dynamo, reformats the data to however you want it then returns it. Quite easy to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal JavaScript example of performing a `GetItem` operation on a DynamoDB table via the AWS API:

```
const DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT = 'https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
let aws = new AwsClient({ accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY });

async function dynamoDbOp(op, opBody) {
    let result = await aws.fetch(DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
            'X-Amz-Target': 'DynamoDB_20120810.' + op
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(opBody)
    });

    return result.json();
}

let dbResponse = await dynamoDbOp('GetItem', {
    TableName: "someTableName",
    Key: {
        someTableKey: {
            S: "someKeyValue"
        }
    }
});

console.log(dbResponse.json());
```

Note that `AwsClient` is a class defined by [aws4fetch](https://github.com/mhart/aws4fetch) which takes care of signing AWS requests for you. See the [AWS GetItem API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) for more info.